# How to list all files in all directory in linux using linux cmd

Tags: linux, bash, command

I'm trying to read all the files available in all directories along with complete path, using bash script. Have tried
`ls -R` cmd but it is not listing the files properly.

My requirement is to have the output which should have complete path for the file.

Comment: Check whether `find` does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want the `find` utility which is recursive by default.

```
find . -type f
```

The `.` means the current pwd/directory

Comment: Or maybe `find "$PWD" -type f` if OP wants absolute paths.

Comment: I'd go with `$(pwd)` sinde `$PWD` can be assigned to something else, intentional or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` command for listing all the files from a particular directory.

```
find /your_path/ -type f 2>/dev/null
```

`/your_path/ : provide the path from where you will execute the command, the output will have the complete path of the files.`

`2>/dev/null : to suppress the STDERR`

right now what you are trying is to list all of the sub-directories using `ls -R`, so this would not fulfill what you are trying to achieve.

See `man ls`:

```
   -R, --recursive
              list subdirectories recursively
```